# Erro ao usar create no sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize-js

Boa noite. Faz pouco tempo que comecei a estudar Node.js e estou tendo problemas em usar o .create no Sequelize.

O erro acontece quando tento cadastrar um usuário:

```
routes.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.create({
        'name': 'nome',
        'email': 'user@email.com',
        'password_hash': '1234567890'
    });
    return res.json('user');
});
```

O erro retornado é:

```
(node:13148) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at User._initValues 
(node:13148) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13148) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Ps: é a primeira vez mexendo com Sequelize, tentei usar o try/catch mas continuou na mesma.

Comment: Olá Shedyhs, da um console.log em user e posta o retorno aqui. Assim: return console.log(user), o objeto está undefined e por isso não tem a propriedade length

Comment: Opa Lucas, não retornou algo diferente.
 
(node:9620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
(node:9620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by 
throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9620) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Comenta o "res.json('user')" e da um console.log nesta variável user. To tentando entender, se esse seu User.create é instanciado, pq esse User.create ele é um método do seu model, né?

Comment: User é um Schema o `.create` é uma função do Sequelize aonde eu passo o objeto para ele adicionar a tabela users.

quando eu do console.log ele nao me retorna nada. acho que é pq o user so recebe valor depois do async terminar.

Comment: Você está retornando uma **string** "user", não o objeto criado

Answer (score 0):

Boa noiteeee!

Você deve retornar um objeto user, assim: return res.json(user);

Você está retornando uma String.

Espero poder ajudar. Eis aqui uma referência.

[How to use Sequelize with Node and Express](https://www.codementor.io/@mirko0/how-to-use-sequelize-with-node-and-express-i24l67cuz)